# Typescript React How to add an a second interface to Prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-typescript

```
import { ReactNode, DetailedHTMLProps, FormHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import {
  FieldValues,
  SubmitHandler,
  useForm,
  UseFormReturn,
} from "react-hook-form";

// I want to add this type to the FormProps interface
// DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>

interface FormProps<TFormValues extends FieldValues> {
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TFormValues>;
  children: (methods: UseFormReturn<TFormValues>) => ReactNode;
}

export const Form = <TFormValues extends Record<string, any>>({
  onSubmit,
  children,
}: FormProps<TFormValues>) => {
  const methods = useForm<TFormValues>();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children(methods)}</form>
  );
};
```

I'm trying to add the `DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>` data type for the form not sure what's the right way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extends` to say that the `FormProps` interface is made of the same content as your desired type, as well as extra properties that you specify.

Make sure not to collide the property names, or if you do so intentionally, the collided properties must have compatible types. In your case, `onSubmit` and `children` collide with properties in `DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>` and have *incompatible* types; you could just use different names instead.

```
interface FormProps<TFormValues extends FieldValues> extends
    DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement> {
    // Make sure not to collide properties with incompatible types
    submitHandler: SubmitHandler<TFormValues>;
    methodsHandler: (methods: UseFormReturn<TFormValues>) => ReactNode;
}

export const Form = <TFormValues extends Record<string, any>>({
    submitHandler,
    methodsHandler,
    ...formAttrs
}: FormProps<TFormValues>) => {
    const methods = useForm<TFormValues>();

    return (
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(submitHandler)} {...formAttrs}>{methodsHandler(methods)}</form>
    );
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktgCJIwrAA2SJAEgCoCyAMgApQRgDO2AGLQQrTgEEYMKMABGAVxhJ+cAL5wAZrxBwARFAIw9AbgBQoSLFxm4duEOBI6JAGoo6ClZlv2AygpyIMAwTCgAdiQMUD72cAr8SCJQILH2AKqJySDIMApQ4T4a2hC6BkYAtAAWEBAA1hWaoqZmZgD0bXAAknAA7hHwMBBwKCQkcDBVwKowAJ5gSBPDk4vZPHyqwOHKUJroSO2dVDT0jOLcvAIAPNnnUjLySipX59kAogwgSNsAfNivog+SC+v1aWx2ezQq1E62uLGy7k8KjgSAAHspIqpHM43B4vPwfij0d8SPxfHZjrQGMx2BcNjdRHdpLJFMp+C9ae9Pt8YH84ACUkCQbybHF+IFgqEIlEkFAAFxwAJBEJhSLRK7w0SI-E-cxxL6TUj8VUy+VwAAUBpqpIVmSSoly+XCGoReJUPwAlHAALyE5DoGDEMjmNStNFWeBoCDhfjwbI+uAurVu1RojGk-BRqAkK6x2ThADm2Aisx+P3NOHJcHFyqlatlaTsVqNJuijbgADou00UvcoGS1Aq1pd2ZqUtr3V7faL7FGY-BmxnvfEsqIk+OU+WPXr7D2QH2yXEOnAAHoAflacUMeQKFqrcSue7g0aVku9OEX-A7VWlDFfIXNGtJVbWUPQ0HAuw7PcDzUH4P2oa1jV-WVLQQo0wKuNo9x+KttzMNRzCAA)